# How to map object to Array only for first level. JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the object:

```
obj = {
    a: 'aVal',
    b: {
        bSub_1: 'bSub_1_value',
        bSub_2: 'bSub_2_value' 
    }
}
```

I need to map this object to an array

`['aVal', {bSub_1: 'bSub_1_value', bSub_2: 'bSub_2_value'}]`

I try to use `Object.values(obj)` but this approach cast all object levels to the array, however, I need casting only first.

How I can do this?

Comment: What is the output you are getting when using `Object.values(obj)` ?

Answer (score 3):

*This answer is more of clarification rather than answer.*

> > .....however, I need casting only first.

*That is not quite clear.*

It seems pretty straight with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

> The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

Please notice how the below snippet produces the exact output you expect:

```js
var obj = {
    a: 'aVal',
    b: {
        bSub_1: 'bSub_1_value',
        bSub_2: 'bSub_2_value' 
    }
}

var res = Object.values(obj);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: wow, you right! This not precisely quotes from my app because I wanted to make an easy example. But in reality, I make mistake. Probably I should delete this question. My first solution absolutely right but backend send invalid data in the deep of object and I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing the same

```
   Object.keys(obj).map(e => obj[e])
```